# Who to write a table using a Shiny input

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Hello the following code returns an error and the app crashes. The error refers to "You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "",
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(textInput("freetext", "Write Something")),
  mainPanel(textOutput("testtext"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$testtext <- renderText(paste("I wrote: ", input$freetext))

  table <- data.frame(wrote = input$freetext)
  
  write.csv(table, "~/testtable.csv", row.names = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried to add the input$freetext into a reactive element but with no luck.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$testtext <- renderText(paste("I wrote: ", input$freetext))

  outtext <- reactive({input$freetext})

  table <- data.frame(wrote = outtext())

  write.csv(table, "~/testtable.csv", row.names = FALSE)

}
```

How can I add the value from input$freetext to the data.frame?

Answer: This worked

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "",
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(textInput("freetext", "Write Something")),
  mainPanel(textOutput("testtext"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$testtext <- renderText(paste("I wrote: ", input$freetext))

  observeEvent(input$freetext, {
    if(nchar(input$freetext) > 0) {
      t <-input$freetext
      table <- data.frame(wrote = t)

      write.csv(table, "/shiny-data/users/scotcan1/testApp/testtable.csv", row.names = FALSE)
      }
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: One can't do that. You need an event to trigger the file writing (for example pressing a button) and then you can do what you want to do in an observer.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added the answer. You are right I needed an observeEvent.

Comment: Great that you found an answer. But please do add it to the question. Add it as answer so that you can take credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = "",
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(textInput("freetext", "Write Something")),
  mainPanel(textOutput("testtext"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$testtext <- renderText(paste("I wrote: ", input$freetext))

  observeEvent(input$freetext, {
    if(nchar(input$freetext) > 0) {
      t <-input$freetext
      table <- data.frame(wrote = t)

      write.csv(table, "/shiny-data/users/scotcan1/testApp/testtable.csv", row.names = FALSE)
      }
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```